# Extracting bits from variables

Tags: c++

I came across a part of code which extracts third bit of `variable` using

```cpp
bool flag = (variable & 0x4) == 0x4;
```

However, the same can be achieved by `bool flag = variable & 4;`. Isn't it? Any reason that this bit extraction specification need to have additional check with `== 0x4` ?

Comment: It's very useful when you need the value from multiple bits. For just a single bit the comparison is not needed, but a personal preference.

Comment: No it's not. It's a different definition of what "3rd bit" means.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I updated the question now.

Comment: Yes, the effect is the same due to implicit conversion. However, if you use this expression outside of a boolean context it is *not* immediately the same, and potentially error-prone. Many people are OK with your alternative code, but many other people (e.g. me) dislike the implicit conversion, and prefer making it explicit via the comparison.

Comment: You might even use `0b0100`.

Comment: You updated the question, but you clearly haven't tried yourself.

Comment: Your question is about `4` versus `0x4`, or `bool b = some_int;` versus `bool b = some_int != 0;`?

Comment: It is to avoid implicit conversion from int to bool.

Comment: Today's compilers are intelligent enough to understand both expressions to be the same. So it is all about readability and flexibility. And look at the first comment about multiple bits, e.g. `bool flag = (variable & 0x6) == 0x4;` or `bool flag = (variable & 0x6) == 0x6;`. Both are different to `bool flag = variable & 0x6;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I feel that is the most relevant answer to my question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is not specified in the standard that the comparison == 0x4 can be optimized out. Only the conversion int to bool. For the comparison the optimizer has to deduce that the result of the and is either 0x0 or 0x4.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have written that I do not refer to the implicit conversion to bool as the step being optimized. Rather the fact that `== 0x4` will definitely result in `0x0` or in `0x4`. For it the optimizer has to analyze the possible range of values of previous calculations (the AND) and use that knowledge for the following calculations (the equality comparison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as far as the compiler is concerned. I didn't even turn on optimizations and got the same assembly:

[variable & 4 == 4](https://www.godbolt.org/z/fn74q15fz) vs [variable & 4](https://www.godbolt.org/z/5vc4d3vvh)

The above is with GCC. There are some subtle differences with MSVC, but it's the same number of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following snippet:

```
enum {FLAG_MASK = 0x04, FLAG_GOOD = 0x04, FLAG_BAD = 0x0};

bool bGood = (variable & FLAG_MASK) == FLAG_GOOD);
```

This code looks very close to your original code.  I would have preferred this code over your original code and the alternative.  Write code for human understanding first.  Let the compiler do the "optimization".

Realize this code would work even if the flag enum definitions (probably in a header file somewhere) changed from 1 bit to 2 (or more) bits.  The .cpp would not have to be touched.

Likewise, the following snippet, while correct in the original enum definition, may not work if the enum was expanded from 1 to 2 (or more) bits:

```
bool bBad = (variable & FLAG_MASK) != FLAG_GOOD);
```

This snippet below is more correct (definitely correct if we later add a new flag `FLAG_BETTER` had the value `0x0C` along with adjusting `FLAG_MASK = 0x0C`).

```
bool bBad = (variable & FLAG_MASK) == FLAG_BAD);
```

Answer (score 0):

`bool flag = (variable & 0x4) == 0x4;`
and
`bool flag = (variable & 0x4);`
will behave the same down to the individual instructions.

But if you want to test for a specific bit - like the 3rd bit - then there are more expressive ways:

1. `bool flag = (variable & ( 1 << flag_position ));` - check for the bit at a specific index
2. `bool flag = (variable & 0b100);` - since C++14 you can write binary literals
3. `std::bitset<sizeof(int)>.test(3);` use a bitset to make it clear this is not a number but a set of bits

And if it is a well-defined set of bits you might also want to use an enum to give each bit-flag a specific meaning.

`enum error_bitflag{out_of_bound, not_numeric, out_of_drinks};`